# vim text color on vsplit (white on white)

Tags: vim, rxvt

I finally and getting around to migrating from aterm to urxvt and have most things setup the way I want, but I still have a hanging issue with vim. When I issue a :vsplit command the text at the bottom of each window showing the filename is white on top of a (nearly) white background making it unreadable. In aterm this test was showing up as black on the while background.

What setting controls this? I've haven't noticed this problem in other places, but haven't really looked for it either.

Here are my .vimrc

```
" .vimrc
" See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html for details

" For multi-byte character support (CJK support, for example):
"set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,big5,euc-jp,euc-kr,gb18030,latin1

set tabstop=4       " Number of spaces that a <Tab> in the file counts for.

set shiftwidth=4    " Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.

"set expandtab       " Use the appropriate number of spaces to insert a <Tab>.
                    " Spaces are used in indents with the '>' and '<' commands
                    " and when 'autoindent' is on. To insert a real tab when
                    " 'expandtab' is on, use CTRL-V <Tab>.

"set smarttab        " When on, a <Tab> in front of a line inserts blanks
                    " according to 'shiftwidth'. 'tabstop' is used in other
                    " places. A <BS> will delete a 'shiftwidth' worth of space
                    " at the start of the line.

set showcmd         " Show (partial) command in status line.

set number          " Show line numbers.

set showmatch       " When a bracket is inserted, briefly jump to the matching
                    " one. The jump is only done if the match can be seen on the
                    " screen. The time to show the match can be set with
                    " 'matchtime'.

set hlsearch        " When there is a previous search pattern, highlight all
                    " its matches.

set incsearch       " While typing a search command, show immediately where the
                    " so far typed pattern matches.

set ignorecase      " Ignore case in search patterns.

set smartcase       " Override the 'ignorecase' option if the search pattern
                    " contains upper case characters.

set backspace=2     " Influences the working of <BS>, <Del>, CTRL-W
                    " and CTRL-U in Insert mode. This is a list of items,
                    " separated by commas. Each item allows a way to backspace
                    " over something.

set autoindent      " Copy indent from current line when starting a new line
                    " (typing <CR> in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O"
                    " command).

set textwidth=0    " Maximum width of text that is being inserted. A longer
                    " line will be broken after white space to get this width.

set formatoptions=c,q,r,t " This is a sequence of letters which describes how
                    " automatic formatting is to be done.
                    "
                    " letter    meaning when present in 'formatoptions'
                    " ------    ---------------------------------------
                    " c         Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting
                    "           the current comment leader automatically.
                    " q         Allow formatting of comments with "gq".
                    " r         Automatically insert the current comment leader
                    "           after hitting <Enter> in Insert mode. 
                    " t         Auto-wrap text using textwidth (does not apply
                    "           to comments)

set ruler           " Show the line and column number of the cursor position,
                    " separated by a comma.

set background=dark " When set to "dark", Vim will try to use colors that look
                    " good on a dark background. When set to "light", Vim will
                    " try to use colors that look good on a light background.
                    " Any other value is illegal.

set mouse=a         " Enable the use of the mouse.

set undofile
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undodir
set undolevels=1000 "maximum number of changes that can be undone
set undoreload=10000 "maximum number lines to save for undo on a buffer reload 

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0
let g:Tex_EnvironmentMaps = 0
let g:Tex_FontMaps = 0
let g:Tex_SectionMaps = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyBS = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyQuote = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeySpace = 0
let g:Tex_SmartKeyDot = 0
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf dvi'
let g:Tex_EscapeChars = '\'

let g:tex_flavor = "latex"

" arduino syntax
autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.pde setlocal ft=arduino

call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

and .Xresources

```
! urxvt settings


!--[Title]--!

!URxvt*title:           urxvt
URxvt*termName:        rxvt-256color
URxvt*termName:        rxvt
URxvt*cursorBlink:     true
URxvt*urgentOnBell:    true

!--[URL Select]--!
URxvt.perl-ext-common:  default,url-select
URxvt.keysym.M-u:       perl:url-select:select_next
URxvt.urlLauncher:      chromium
URxvt.underlineURLs:    true

!--[Fonts]--!

URxvt.font: 9x15
!URxvt.font: -*-terminus-*-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-u
!URxvt.font: -*-droid sans mono-*-*-*-*-12-*-*-*-*-*-*-u
!URxvt.font:               xft:terminus:pixelsize=10:antialias=true
!
URxvt.scrollBar:         false
URxvt.skipBuiltinGlyphs: true

!--[Urxvt Options]--!

URxvt.boldMode:          false
!URxvt.imLocale:          en_US.UTF-8
URxvt.loginShell:        true
URxvt.saveLines:         4096
!urxvt.geometry:          110x40
URxvt.borderless:        true
!URxvt.xftAntialias:      true
URxvt.jumpScroll:        true
!URxvt.tintColor:         white
URxvt.internalBorder:    0
URxvt.cursorBlink:       false
URxvt.cursorColor:       #dd9900
URxvt.cursorColor2:      #000000
URxvt.background:        #FFFFFF
URxvt.foreground:        #ddccbb
URxvt.colorBD:           #ffffff
URxvt.colorIT:           #bbbbbb
URxvt.colorUL:           #999999
URxvt.underlineColor:    #999999
!Xcursor.theme: CG

!## teh transparency stuff
URxvt.inheritPixmap: true
URxvt.tintColor: white
URxvt.shading: 0


! xscreensaver ---------------------------------------------------------------

xscreensaver.Dialog.headingFont:        -*-dina-bold-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.bodyFont:           -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.labelFont:          -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.unameFont:          -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.buttonFont:         -*-dina-bold-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.Dialog.dateFont:           -*-dina-medium-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
xscreensaver.passwd.passwdFont:         -*-dina-bold-r-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
!general dialog box (affects main hostname, username, password text)

xscreensaver.Dialog.foreground:         #ffffff
xscreensaver.Dialog.background:         #000000
xscreensaver.Dialog.topShadowColor:     #000000
xscreensaver.Dialog.bottomShadowColor:  #000000
xscreensaver.Dialog.Button.foreground:  #666666
xscreensaver.Dialog.Button.background:  #ffffff
!username/password input box and date text colour
xscreensaver.Dialog.text.foreground:    #666666
xscreensaver.Dialog.text.background:    #ffffff
xscreensaver.Dialog.internalBorderWidth:24
xscreensaver.Dialog.borderWidth:        20
xscreensaver.Dialog.shadowThickness:    2
!timeout bar (background is actually determined by Dialog.text.background)
xscreensaver.passwd.thermometer.foreground:  #666666
xscreensaver.passwd.thermometer.background:  #000000
xscreensaver.passwd.thermometer.width:       8

! terminal colors ------------------------------------------------------------


URxvt*background: #000000
URxvt*foreground: #bfbdc0

!black
URxvt*color0: #000000
URxvt*color8: #686773

!red
URxvt*color1: #cd0000
URxvt*color9: #ff0000

!green
URxvt*color2: #00cd00
URxvt*color10:#00ff00

!yellow
URxvt*color3: #cdcd00
URxvt*color11:#ffff00

!blue
URxvt*color4: #6767cd
URxvt*color12:#6767ff

!purple
URxvt*color5: #cd00cd
URxvt*color13:#ff00ff

!cyan
URxvt*color6: #00cdcd
URxvt*color14:#00ffff

!white
URxvt*color7: #faebd7
URxvt*color15:#ffffff

! attempt to get vim to read the colors correctly
URxvt.intensityStyles:  false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:hi StatusLine
:help hl-StatusLine
```

(Response to comments.)
If you need more context, then scroll up to the top of the section (or `:help highlight-default`):

```
These are the default highlighting groups.  These groups are used by the
'highlight' option default.  Note that the highlighting depends on the value
of 'background'.  You can see the current settings with the ":highlight"
command.
```

The line you describe, showing the file name, is the status line.  (`:help status-line` and scroll up if you need more context.)  The setting that controls the display of the status line is the `StatusLine` highlight group (not an option).  You can inspect the current setting with `:hi StatusLine`, and you can change it with, for example.

```
:hi StatusLine term=bold cterm=bold
```

See `:help :highlight` for more options.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how to use that information. The first command gives me "StatusLine     xxx term=bold,reverse cterm=bold,reverse gui=bold,reverse". The help section that the second line takes me to just gives a one-line description of StatusLine as the status line of the current window.